# D3 v4 re-rendering nested objects, having problems with `enter()` and `exit()`

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to display a number of circles wrapped in `<g>` elements. This wrapping thing is important for me as in real world I want other elements to be in my group as well. The problem is, circles in the below example wont get displayed by first `render(myObjects)` call, and if you hit **render** button they are shown.

Second problem is when I press **update** the previously drawn circles are not removed and the new ones will render on top of them.

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('width', 250)
        .attr('height', 250);

    //render the data
    function render(datum) {
        //Bind 
        var groups = svg.selectAll("g").data(datum);
        groups.enter().append('g');

        var circles = groups.append("circle").attr('r', 10)
            .attr('cx', function(d) {
                return d.x;
            })
            .attr('cy', function(d) {
                return d.y;
            });

        groups.exit().remove();
    }

    var myObjects = [{ x: 100, y: 100 }, { x: 130, y: 120 }, { x: 80, y: 180 }, { x: 180, y: 80 }, { x: 180, y: 40 }];
    var newObjects = [{ x: 200, y: 120 }, { x: 150, y: 160 }, { x: 20, y: 80 }, { x: 80, y: 60 }, { x: 100, y: 20 }];

    function removeEls() {
        svg.selectAll('circle').remove();
    }

    render(myObjects);
```

```css
svg {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px
}

button {
    float: left
}

text {
    text-anchor: middle;
}

circle {
    fill: orange;
    stroke: orange;
    fill-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="render(newObjects)">Update</button>
<button onclick="render(myObjects);">Render</button>
<button onclick="removeEls();">removeEls</button>
```

Comment: put removeEls() into your render() to delete circles before draw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 little issues in your code :

1. You have added the circles in the `groups` instead of `groups.enter()`, hence the issue of not displaying the circles at the first draw
2. You forget to add an identifier when you add the data, so the script is unable to detect which data is new and which data is not. I added a d.x/d.y identifier, which works in your case, but I advice you to add a true unique identifier. Like add a field id in your list of objects.

Here is the snippet with the corrections :

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 250)
    .attr('height', 250)
    .append('g');

//render the data
function render(datum) {
    //Bind 
    var groups = svg.selectAll("g").data(datum, d => (d.x)/(d.y));
    var groupEnter = groups.enter().append('g');

    var circles =        groupEnter.append("circle").attr('r', 10)
        .attr('cx', function(d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr('cy', function(d) {
            return d.y;
        });

    groups.exit().remove();
}

var myObjects = [{ x: 100, y: 100 }, { x: 130, y: 120 }, { x: 80, y: 180},{ x: 180, y: 80 }, { x: 180, y: 40 }];
var newObjects = [{ x: 200, y: 120 }, { x: 150, y: 160 }, { x: 20, y: 80}, { x: 80, y: 60 }, { x: 100, y: 20 }];

function removeEls() {
    svg.selectAll('circle').remove();
}

render(myObjects);
```

```css
svg {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px
}

button {
    float: left
}

text {
    text-anchor: middle;
}

circle {
    fill: orange;
    stroke: orange;
    fill-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="render(newObjects)">Update</button>
<button onclick="render(myObjects);">Render</button>
<button onclick="removeEls();">removeEls</button>
```